# swiftui storing reference data doesn't keep references between objects

Tags: swiftui, reference, save, load, userdefaults

I have an array called nameList of NameObjects which are classes.
I have a second array called playerList, which contains NameObjects from nameList.
If I change properties of a nameObject in nameList, this changes are also visible in playlist because NameObjects are Reference Types.
The nameObjects of playerList and nameList have the same memory address, as expected.

When the app is closed, nameList and playerList are stored in UserDefaults.
When the app is reopened the lists are loaded from UserDefaults.

The content of nameList and layerList are correctly rebuilt.
However, the reference dependency is destroyed.
Now the nameObjects of playerList and nameList have different memory addresses.
The connection is broken.

Is there a way to save reference Types in UserDefaults with keeping the references alive.

The following code demonstrates the effect with very short lists with 1 element only.

```
    import SwiftUI

    @main
    struct SavingPointerTypesApp: App {
        private var nLM: NameListManager = NameListManager()
        var body: some Scene {
            WindowGroup {
                ContentView()
                    .environmentObject(nLM)
            }
        }
    }

    import Foundation
    import SwiftUI

    class NameListManager: ObservableObject {
        // MARK: - Published Objects
        // List of active players
        @Published
        var playerList: [NameItem] = []
        // List of all persons who are registered
        @Published
        var nameList: [NameItem] =  []
        
        init() {
            fillLists()
        }
        
        
        
        
        func fillLists() {
            // Fill name list
            nameList.append(NameItem("Adam"))
            //Fill player list
            playerList.append(nameList[0])
        }

        
        // MARK: - Save/Store/Delete Methods
        func load(type: ListType){
            let key = type.rawValue
            
            if let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: key) as? Data {
                if let list = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode([NameItem].self, from: data){
                    switch type {
                    case .playerList:
                        self.playerList = list
                    case .nameList:
                        self.nameList = list
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        func save(type: ListType) {
            let key = type.rawValue
            switch type {
            case .playerList:
                UserDefaults.standard.set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(self.playerList), forKey: key)
            case .nameList:
                UserDefaults.standard.set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(self.nameList), forKey: key)
            }
        }
    }


    class NameItem: Encodable, Decodable, Identifiable {
        var name: String
        var id =  UUID()
        
        init( _ name: String) {
            self.name = name
        }
    }

    enum ListType: String {
        case playerList = "player-list"
        case nameList  = "name-list"
    }


    import SwiftUI

    struct ContentView: View {
        @EnvironmentObject var nML: NameListManager
        @State var nameAddrBefore: String = ""
        @State var playerAddrBefore: String = ""
        @State var nameAddrAfter: String = ""
        @State var playerAddrAfter: String = ""


        var body: some View {
            makeView()
            .onAppear(){
                generateAddresses()
            }
        }
        
        

        @ViewBuilder
        func makeView() -> some View {
            List() {
                VStack {
                    Text("Names before save/load").font(.title3)
                    Text("NameList  : \(nML.nameList[0].name)")
                    Text("PlayerList: \(nML.playerList[0].name)")
                    Text("Addresses before save/load").font(.title3)
                    Text("Address name  : " + nameAddrBefore)
                    Text("Address player: " + playerAddrBefore)
                        .padding(.bottom,20)
                }

                VStack{
                    Text("Names after save/load").font(.title3)
                    Text("NameList  : \(nML.nameList[0].name)")
                    Text("PlayerList: \(nML.playerList[0].name)")
                    Text("Addresses after save/load").font(.title3)
                    Text("Address name  : " + nameAddrAfter)
                    Text("Address player: " + playerAddrAfter)
                }
            }
        }

        
        func generateAddresses() {
            var addr: UnsafeMutableRawPointer = Unmanaged.passUnretained(nML.nameList[0]).toOpaque()
            var addrInt = Int(bitPattern: addr)
            self.nameAddrBefore = String(format:"%02X", addrInt)
            
            addr = Unmanaged.passUnretained(nML.playerList[0]).toOpaque()
            addrInt = Int(bitPattern: addr)
            self.playerAddrBefore = String(format:"%02X", addrInt)
            
            //Save data
            nML.save(type: .nameList)
            nML.save(type: .playerList)
            
            //Load Data
            nML.load(type: .nameList)
            nML.load(type: .playerList)
            
            addr = Unmanaged.passUnretained(nML.nameList[0]).toOpaque()
            addrInt = Int(bitPattern: addr)
            self.nameAddrAfter = String(format:"%02X", addrInt)
            
            addr = Unmanaged.passUnretained(nML.playerList[0]).toOpaque()
            addrInt = Int(bitPattern: addr)
            self.playerAddrAfter = String(format:"%02X", addrInt)
        }
    }




    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(NameListManager())
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don’t store the objects in playerList, instead store some identifier for the objects so you can recreate the correct reference to the corresponding objects in the main list.

Comment: `NameItem` should probably be a `struct` -- that will help other issues down the line as well

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Comment: In your `SavingPointerTypesApp` try using `@StateObject private var nLM = NameListManager()`.
see also: [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)